# Update Query Working, Insert Query Not Working (If Else) in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

In My For Loop Condition, If Purchase Id is posted from client Form, Record will be Updated, else Record Will be Inserted.

Update will be Working Perfectly but, Insert is Not Working. When i use echo query, it will be insert new Record. whats my Issue.. My Code is Below.

```
$countproducts=count($data['product']);     

    $producttotalamount=0;
    $productvatamount=0;
    $productgrandtotalamount=0; 

    for($i=0; $i<$countproducts; $i++){

    $producttotalamount += $data['quantity'][$i]*$data['prodct_rate'][$i]; 
    $productvatamount += ($data['vatpercentage'][$i]/100)*($data['quantity'][$i]*$data['prodct_rate'][$i]); 
    $productgrandtotalamount += ($data['quantity'][$i]*$data['prodct_rate'][$i]) + (($data['vatpercentage'][$i]/100)*($data['quantity'][$i]*$data['prodct_rate'][$i]));

    if($data["purchaseitemsid"][$i] == ''){ 

    $insprdtotamts=$data['quantity'][$i]*$data['prodct_rate'][$i]; 
    $insprdvatamts=($data['vatpercentage'][$i]/100)*$insprdtotamts; 
    $insprdgrdtotamts=($data['quantity'][$i]*$data['prodct_rate'][$i]) + (($data['vatpercentage'][$i]/100)*$insprdtotamts);

    $insertpurchaseitemsrecord=Purchaseitems::Create(['purchaseid' => $data['hdnid'],'product' => $data['product'][$i],'quantity' => $data['quantity'][$i],'unit' => $data['unit'][$i],'add_quantity' => $data['quantity_add'][$i],'add_unit' => $data['unit_add'][$i],'product_rate'=>$data['prodct_rate'][$i],'product_amount' => $insprdtotamts,'vat_percentage' => $data['vatpercentage'][$i],'vat_amount' => $insprdvatamts,'prod_total_amount'=>$insprdgrdtotamts,'company_id'=>$companyids,'user_id' => $usersid,'created_by' => $usersid,]);    

    } else {    

    $updprdtotamts=$data['quantity'][$i]*$data['prodct_rate'][$i]; 
    $updprdvatamts=($data['vatpercentage'][$i]/100)*$updprdtotamts; 
    $updprdgrdtotamts=($data['quantity'][$i]*$data['prodct_rate'][$i]) + (($data['vatpercentage'][$i]/100)*$updprdtotamts); 

    $updateqry= Purchaseitems::where('id', $data['purchaseitemsid'][$i])->update(['product' => $data['product'][$i],'quantity' => $data['quantity'][$i],'unit' => $data['unit'][$i],'add_quantity' => $data['quantity_add'][$i],'add_unit' => $data['unit_add'][$i],'product_rate' => $data['prodct_rate'][$i],'product_amount' => $updprdtotamts,'vat_percentage' => $data['vatpercentage'][$i],'vat_amount'=>$updprdvatamts,'prod_total_amount'=>$updprdgrdtotamts,'updated_by' => $usersid,]);       

    }   

    }
```

Comment: first check it's  coming inside the else part or not

Comment: Yah, Its Coming Both Part @JYoThI

Comment: Is there any column exist which has no default value in the table and also you not passing that in insert query ??

Comment: i suggest you use `updateOrCreate` function .. it is much easier than this ..

Comment: first check $updateqry= Purchaseitems::where('id', $data['purchaseitemsid'][$i])->get();  print_r($updateqry); did have row for specific id like this  @Karthik

Comment: @Karthik and if you use `Purchaseitems::insert([ ....` ?

Comment: Same Issue Found... @Autista_z

Comment: why are you doing both the queries differently when you can do it together using `Purchaseitems::updateOrCreate(['id' => $data['purchaseitemsid'][$i], rest of your data])`

Comment: `Purchaseitems::Create` it's youe one method? If not, then you should use `create` instead

Answer (score 0):

- dd($data) and check if you are getting id while insert operation, it should be null or empty while doing insert operation

Comment: Its Return Posted Value.. @Nikhil Radadiya

Comment: Can you post it here?

Answer (score 0):

## Laravel Case :

Use this : `Purchaseitems::create($array);` instead of `Purchaseitems::Create($array);`

### OR

```
$pItem  = new Purchaseitems();
$pItem->purchaseid = $setPurchaseid;
  ...
  ...
  ...
$pItem->save();
```

Comment: Not Working @Rashedul Islam Sagor